# Python - Get all values of field in JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a geoJSON file, and I'd like to extract all the possible values in a subfield. So for a two items long json it would be like this:

```
data['features'][0]['properties']['cellId']
#returns 38
data['features'][1]['properties']['cellId']
#returns 51
```

I'd like to return `[38, 51]`. Is it possible? I tried

```
data['features'][0:]['properties']['cellId']
```

but it doesn't work, since `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for element in data['features']:
    print(element['properties']['cellId'])
```

Or use list comprehension if you want to store these instead of just printing them individually:

```
cell_ids = [element['properties']['cellId'] for element in data['features']]
print(cell_ids)
# [38, 51]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` to collect the data you want. In your example its:

```
[data['features'][i]['properties']['cellId'] for i in range(len(data))]
```

**Updated**: Sorry, the better/pythonic code is in the answer gave by @DeepSpace, just iterate `data['features']`, not `range(len(data))`

Comment: You should use the Python way of iterating rather than `for i in range(len(..))`, and you should also iterate over `data['features']` instead of `data`.

Comment: @DeepSpace, thanks for your kind remind, I was updating my answer and voted up yours;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
[i['properties']['cellId'] for i in data['features']]
```

Taking @DeepSpace 's comments, use this.